# Does vertical partitioning is possible in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

i am new to mysql.i want to do vertical partition on table using mysql.i found only horizontal partition in  some website.Please tell me vertical partition is possible or not ?please give example how to do vertical partition using mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in support for vertical partitioning is mysql. What you can do is to create multiple tables with the same primary key and split the fields between the tables.

You will use joins to query all fields for a record.